# Which of my queries is more efficient?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Which one of the following queries is more efficient and why? According to execution plan they both have the same total cost, but I am not sure if that alone is a good indicator of overall performance.

1>

```
SELECT MIN(ROWID), MAX(ROWID)
FROM tab_a
WHERE status = 0
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 'X'
    FROM tab_b
    WHERE status = 0
    AND number = assembly_number
    AND ROWID >= :min_rowid
    AND ROWID <= :max_rowid
)
;
```

2>

```
SELECT MIN(ROWID), MAX(ROWID)
FROM tab_a
WHERE status = 0
AND assembly_number IN (
    SELECT number
    FROM tab_b
    WHERE status = 0
    AND ROWID >= :min_rowid
    AND ROWID <= :max_rowid
)
;
```

Comment: That will greatly depend on the indexing on the tables.

Comment: @astander: Really? One would think that the query planner treats them as equivalent (which seems to be the case as it shows the same cost).

Comment: Can you show the execution plans for both? (It looks like they might be identical).

Comment: if assembly_number is indexed then maybe number 2 is more efficient

Comment: @AppleGrew have a look at http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:953229842074

Comment: the first that i looked at the syntax is was both different.. but someone edited it and it became identical.. how can we know now for sure -_-

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the query optimizer would optimize both into the same query.

Comment: Compare the execution plans.

Answer (score 0):

if  assembly_number is indexed then following query will be better.

```
SELECT MIN(ROWID), MAX(ROWID)
FROM tab_a
WHERE status = 0
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 'X'
    FROM tab_b
    WHERE status = 0
    AND number = assembly_number
    AND ROWID >= :min_rowid
    AND ROWID <= :max_rowid
);
```

Comment: How do you know that? Oracle's optimizer is quite smart, and I wouldn't be surprised if both queries result in exactly the same execution plan.

Comment: Well I added index on `status + number`. The cost has decreased compared to last plan. However, still I get same cost plans for both 1 & 2 queries. According to http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:953229842074 the choice simple depends on inner or outer which query has more data. In my case both have same amount.